# Reindex Product after Cronjob in Magento - Configurable Products showing Out Of Stock

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have written a Extension that updates some custom shipping value Attributes on save for Magento 1.7. All working fine, when saving the product all is updated as it should. However I also have the need for a cronjob to update them each night in case I need to change shipping costs throught the board.

Is all working, and is updating the attribute values correctly, however on the frontend all configurable products are showing as `Out of Stock`, Simple Products are fine.

If I go to the admin, just click in the master product and save it without doing anything it shows back as `In Stock` on the frontend. Also if I go to Indexes and reindex `Product Attributes` it again shows as In stock on the frontend. I presume then that my cronjob needs to update the indexer on saving each product.

Looking around I used the following code, however it doesn't seem to update the product, and wondered if anyone could help. I have tried different variations around the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` and `TYPE_SAVE` but can't find what I am supposed to use!

```
$updateProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());

$updateProduct->setShippingLabel($shippData['delivery_type']);
$updateProduct->setShippingPrice($shippData['price']);
$updateProduct->setShippingNote($shippData['notes']);
try {
   $updateProduct->save();
   $updateProduct->setForceReindexRequired(true);
   Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->processEntityAction(
   $updateProduct, 
     Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 
     Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE 
   );

   echo $updateProduct->getId()." Successfully Updated \n";
   } catch(Exception $e){
     echo $e->getMessage().$updateProduct->getId()."\n";
 }
```

**Update 17/5/2013 20:28**

Have been playing with the code and this amendment seems to work, if it is totally useless and a stupid way of doing it please let me know

```
$updateProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
$updateProduct->setShippingLabel($shippData['delivery_type']);
$updateProduct->setShippingPrice($shippData['price']);
$updateProduct->setShippingNote($shippData['notes']);
try {
   $updateProduct->save();
   $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product->getId());
   $stockItem->setForceReindexRequired(true);
   Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->processEntityAction(
       $stockItem, 
       Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item::ENTITY,
       Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE
   );
   echo $updateProduct->getId()." Successfully Updated \n";
} catch(Exception $e){
   echo $e->getMessage().$updateProduct->getId()."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the execution of your cron job you can update your indexer:

```
$indexingProcesses = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection(); 
foreach ($indexingProcesses as $process) {
$process->reindexEverything();
}
```

Comment: I think the trouble is it goes through over 8000 products so it takes a rather long time to run, so to wait until it is all finished would have quite a long time where items are showing as out of stock and not allow any purchases to be made

Answer (score -2):

After the execution of your cron job you can update your indexer:

```
$indexingProcesses = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection(); 
foreach ($indexingProcesses as $process) {
$process->reindexEverything();
}
```

hello dhawal if i have to run a cron job for to re-index product on site, I have to placed the code that you have mention with this code

```
$updateProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
$updateProduct->`setShippingLabel`($shippData['delivery_type']);
$updateProduct->setShippingPrice($shippData['price']);
$updateProduct->setShippingNote($shippData['notes']);
try {
   $updateProduct->save();
   $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product->getId());
   $stockItem->setForceReindexRequired(true);
   Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->processEntityAction(
       $stockItem, 
       Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item::ENTITY,
       Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE
   );
   echo $updateProduct->getId()." Successfully Updated \n";
} catch(Exception $e){
   echo $e->getMessage().$updateProduct->getId()."\n";
}
```

at same page ??